# Given similar $A,B$ matrices how to find a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given 2 similar square matrices $A$ and $B$ of same order,how to get hold of a non-singular matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$.One way I know is to solve the system $PB=AP$ which often becomes hard to compute.Is there any other way to find such a matrix $P$.Is there any aspect of linear transformation and change of basis?I have searched the links in mathstackexchange dealing these questions but the answers do not satisfy me.Please suggest a way to compute such a matrix $P$.

Comment: Notice that it is not a duplicate,I am not satisfied by the answers I found for similar question on this site.

Comment: I am assuming A and B are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are similar, so that such a $P$ exists:

1. If they are diagonalizable, then $A = S \Lambda S^{-1}$ and $B = T \Lambda T^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of their eigenvalues, and $S$ and $T$ are the matrices of their eigenvectors, respectively. Therefore, $B = T(S^{-1}AS)T^{-1} = (TS^{-1}) A (ST^{-1}) = (ST^{-1})^{-1}A(ST^{-1})$, so we take $P = ST^{-1}$.
2. If they are not diagonalizable, you can use the Jordan form instead of $\Lambda$ and matrices of generalized eigenvectors instead of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: I actually do not know diagonalization,Jordan process and all that.I am new in this topic.